# Battery voltage drops to 0

Tags: voltage, batteries, battery-charging

I have this type of battery. When it was fully charged I read with the multimeter aroud 38-39 volts. Now I read 21 volts. The question is: When I connect the battery (discharged - 21,22 v) to a bldc motor load, the voltage drops to 0, the motor only spins for 2 seconds every time o plug the battery. Do you have any ideea why the voltage drops to 0 ?[image]

Comment: Your battery can't supply the motor's inrush current.

Comment: There's probably a battery protection circuit built in which is trying to protect the battery from being over-discharged. 21V for a 38-39V Li-Ion is dead-flat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lithium-polymer batteries don't like being discharged too deeply.  Doing so damages them in a way that can cause a fire on subsequent charging.

So nearly all LiPo packs have a protection circuit built into the pack that prevents the battery from being discharged too deeply (by cutting off the current).  Some of these will switch off permanently.

The behavior you are seeing is due to that protection circuit.

Comment: Why don't you just charge it up?

Comment: I will but I just wanted to know what is happening. I didn't know that the battery has a protection circuit. Thank you !